# Error when trying to add VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

[image]
after trying to add VectorDrawable, there was a mistake, but regained it all back when there are new , please tell me what is the problem ?

```
Error:(10, 40) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(67, 34) error: package R does not exist
Error:(11, 40) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(68, 34) error: package R does not exist
Error:(11, 40) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(68, 34) error: package R does not exist
Error:(11, 40) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(68, 34) error: package R does not exist
Error:(11, 40) error: cannot find symbol class R
Error:(68, 34) error: package R does not exist
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: can you show the definition of R?

Comment: its probably the most frequent question of entrice android-universe...

Answer (score 0):

This looks as a R issue and when R answer with "package R does not exist", you should read back the command you've run and see if one of the function does not refer to a package that needs to be installed... sometimes it's also mispelling stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.kroket94.osagroup123.fragments;
```

`enter code here`   import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import com.example.kroket94.osagroup123.R;

```
</**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentGlavnaya.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentGlavnaya#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentGlavnaya extends android.app.Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentGlavnaya() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentGlavnaya.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentGlavnaya newInstance(String param1, String param2)    {
        FragmentGlavnaya fragment = new FragmentGlavnaya();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_glavnaya, container, false);
    }
```

2 fragments errors "R"